# How to get FloatSlider interactive parameters to use in another function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm writing a code to fit a curve to experimental data. To manually adjust the parameters, I'm using a interactive floatslider for the parameters a and b and displaying the adjustment. I would like to get the interact parameters a and b to use as an initial condition for the linear regression.
How can i get the parameters a and b from the function?

I tried to put a return(a,b), but i can't the parameters. There is the code:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#creat data input (experimetal)
x = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=100)
var=np.random.normal(size=100)
y=3*x+var+5

def plot_guess(a,b):
plt.scatter(x,y);
x_values=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
plt.plot(x_values, a\*x_values+b,lw=3,color='black')
return(a,b)

interact(plot_guess, a=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=5, step=0.2, value=1), b=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=5, step=0.2, value=0));
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, review your question, but if I get, you tried to define a and b before pass as parameter and just get the 'a.value'?

```py
a=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=5, step=0.2, value=1)
b=widgets.FloatSlider(min=0, max=5, step=0.2, value=0)

def plot_guess(a, b):
    plt.scatter(x,y);
    x_values=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
    plt.plot(x_values, a*x_values+b,lw=3,color='black')
    return(a,b)

interact(plot_guess, a=a, b=b)

a.value, b.value
```